# Firebug won't display console feeds for some of my sites

Tags: firefox, firebug

Using Firebug v1.20b7 with Firefox v3.0.1 I use firebug a lot for web devlopment.

I have very often the problem that Firebug won't show its web console for seeing the `POSTs` and `GETs`. I can view all the other tabs, including the NET tab that gives me a lot of the same information that the CONSOLE tab does.

Curious if anyone else has had this problem, and maybe a solution, or maybe this is a bug of Firebug.

Answer (score 2):

There is a limitation in firebug (or rather, in firefox iteself), which will be fixed in one of the newer Firefox releases.

The bug is caused by the fact that firebug needs to send data *a second time* to monitor what's going on in the connection.

There's now a special API hook in the firefox trunk that should prevent this workaround in the future, so that firebug can really  spy on what's going on :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, 1.20b7 is technically a *beta* version of Firebug. :)

I've had problems with certain features off and on, but a restart of Firefox seems to fix it more often than not.